# How to defining the IaaS Provider of cloudstack for Embedded Auto-Scaler of WSO2 ELB

Tags: wso2, iaas

I am configuring the Embedded Auto-Scaler of WSO2 ELB following the link "http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ELB203/Configuring+the+Embedded+Auto-Scaler", It only define IaaS Provider of EC2 and openstack in /repository/conf/cloud-controller.xml, Unfortunately, I have to use the IaaS Provider of cloudstack.

Does anyone know how to configure IaaS Provider of cloudstack for Embedded Auto-Scaler of WSO2 ELB.

I will appreciate if you can tell me how to configure the following files:

1. /repository/conf/cloud-controller.xml
2. The Cartridge XML file in /repository/deployment/server/cartridges/ folder
3. The Service XML file in /repository/deployment/server/services/ folder

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, WSO2 ELB supports EC2 and OpenStack. However you can configure any IaaS supported by [jclouds](http://jclouds.org) by writing a custom implementation.

WSO2 ELB is also used in WSO2 Stratos 2.0 and you can find more information at Wiki Docs for Stratos: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Stratos200/WSO2+Stratos+Documentation

You can find more information about providing support for a new IaaS provider from following link.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Stratos200/Providing+Support+for+a+New+IaaS+Provider

> /repository/conf/cloud-controller.xml

Refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Stratos200/Cloud+Controller+Configuration+Files

You can configure your IaaS provider here.

> The Cartridge XML file in /repository/deployment/server/cartridges/ folder

Refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Stratos200/Sample+Cartridge+XML+Files for a sample. This is where you define the image id for your IaaS provider.

> The Service XML file in /repository/deployment/server/services/ folder

Refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Stratos200/Sample+Service+XML+Files for a sample. Service XML defines a service cluster.

Reading about Stratos [Architecture](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Stratos200/Architecture) might help to understand the context regarding all the files above.

Please subscribe to WSO2 mailing [lists](http://wso2.com/mail), if you have not subscribed already.

Comment: I asked you to subscribe to mailing lists as you can get help when you are developing the IaaS provider for CloudStack

Comment: Thank you for youre advice, I have subscribed mailing lists now.

Comment: Great! Please send a mail to dev@ if you find any issues with developing the IaaS provider for CloudStack.